# APScheduler and Unmarshallable Objects

Tags: python, dcom, apscheduler

I would like to execute a function every second. I used the `APScheduler` and it works fine. However, there's a great performance penalty due to the fact that during each job I recreate the object which handles the connection to a server. I would like to create this connection object only once in the main thread and then pass it and reuse it when jobs are triggered. Problem is the connection object uses `DCOM` and I get `unmarshallable object` error.

I also tested an infinite loop approach combined with a sleep function but I noticed time drifting in this case. However, I create the `DCOM` object only once and performance wise looks a lot better.

Is there a workaround the `unmarshallable object` error and continue using `APScheduler`? Or, if this is not possible: How do I get rid of the time drifting issue in the infinite loop approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using `threading.Event` and keeping the client in the main thread:

```
import threading
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import logging

# Start the scheduler
logging.basicConfig()
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

ev = threading.Event()

# Schedule job_function
sched.add_interval_job(job, Ts, args=[ev])

while True:
    ev.wait()
    # do stuff with the unmarshallable object

    ev.clear()

def job(ev):
    ev.set()
```

I haven't noticed time drifts with this approach.